# Can't connect to K8S cluster from kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am running `kubectl` from Mac OS M1 laptop. There is a K8S cluster deployed to gcp and I have logged in from cli `gcloud auth login`. Then I run below command to authenticate GKS credential

```bash
> gcloud container clusters get-credentials gcp-test --zone australia-southeast2-a
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for gcp-test.
```

it looks ok but I got below error when run `get pods`

```bash
> kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: EOF
```

The version of `kubectl` I am using is

```bash
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.13-eks-fb459a0", GitCommit:"55bd5d5cb7d32bc35e4e050f536181196fb8c6f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-24T20:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.13-eks-fb459a0", GitCommit:"55bd5d5cb7d32bc35e4e050f536181196fb8c6f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-24T20:35:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The K8S cluster version in GCP is `1.24.5-gke.600`. Does anyone know why I get `Unable to connect to the server: EOF` error? It seems like not able to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already a config for an EKS cluster. Maybe gcloud added a new context to your kubeconfig file, but the old one is still the active one.

Use

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

to check if there are multiple contexts.

Use

```
kubectl config use-context <context-name>
```

to set the active context.

You could also examine your kubeconfig file. The default location is

```
~/.kube/config
```

but can be overridden by `KUBECONFIG` environment variable. To find that out, execute

```
echo $KUBECONFIG
```

Could also be that gcloud added the context to the default kubeconfig file but you have a different on set with the `KUBECONFIG` env variable that contains the EKS context.